# Trying to reset tic tac toe game

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing Tic Tac Toe game in C# WPF. Here is my code

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace TicTacToe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public bool isPlayer1Turn { get; set; }
        public int counter { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NewGame();
        }
        

        public void NewGame()
        {
            counter = 0;
            isPlayer1Turn = false;

            button_0_0.Content = string.Empty;
            button_1_0.Content = string.Empty;
            button_2_0.Content = string.Empty;
            button_0_1.Content = string.Empty;
            button_1_1.Content = string.Empty;
            button_2_1.Content = string.Empty;
            button_0_2.Content = string.Empty;
            button_1_2.Content = string.Empty;
            button_2_2.Content = string.Empty;
        }

       

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
      
            if(counter>9)
            {
               NewGame();
               return;
            }
            var whichButton = sender as Button;

            if (whichButton.Content != null)
            {
                whichButton.Content += "";
                counter += 0;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                if (isPlayer1Turn)                      // this can by replaced by:
                    isPlayer1Turn = false;              // isPlayer1Turn ^= true;
                else
                    isPlayer1Turn = true;
                    whichButton.Content = isPlayer1Turn ? "O" : "X";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with "New Game" method. I added this because I want to reset the game whenever move counter is greater than 9. When I add this method my buttons are empty even when I click them. If I delete this method I can click on buttons and they are switching to "X" or "O" without any problem. Whats the problem? Is there any other method to reset the game without setting buttons content to empty string?

Comment: you initialize your buttons with an empty string, and in Button_Click you check 'if (whichButton.Content != null)', so this is always true because an empty string is not the same as Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are checking button's Content with null in your Button_Click method?

You need check Button's Content with string.Empty and for restarting it check equality of "counter"  varible value to 9:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (counter == 9)
    {
        NewGame();
        return;
    }
    var whichButton = sender as Button;

    if (whichButton.Content != string.Empty)
    {
        whichButton.Content += "";
        counter += 0;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
        if (isPlayer1Turn)                      // this can by replaced by:
            isPlayer1Turn = false;              // isPlayer1Turn ^= true;
        else
            isPlayer1Turn = true;
        whichButton.Content = isPlayer1Turn ? "O" : "X";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works now and I understand why. Game was not reseting when I had ">9" condition because all fields were not empty so after click counter was not incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your if statement is getting executed always before the the else statement.

Try to replace below block

```
if (whichButton.Content != null)
{
    whichButton.Content += "";
    counter += 0;
}
```

with

```
if (whichButton.Content != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(whichButton.Content.ToString()))
{
    whichButton.Content += "";
    counter += 0;
}
```